# Error using custom comparator for sorting map

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, stl

I'm trying to sort the keys of a Sparse Matrix by row and column, and I want to use a map for this purpose. I added a custom comparator to ensure that, but I facing the following compilation error:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wpedantic   -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/map:60,
                 from Matrix.hh:1,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const _Key&) const [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Val = std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; _Compare = compare_keys; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:1215:31:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::size_type std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::count(const key_type&) const [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = compare_keys; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]’
Matrix.hh:23:9:   required from ‘bool Matrix<T>::emplace(int, int, T) [with T = int]’
main.cpp:7:5:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:2572:8: error: no match for call to ‘(const compare_keys) (const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)’
 2571 |       return (__j == end()
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2572 |        || _M_impl._M_key_compare(__k,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2573 |      _S_key(__j._M_node))) ? end() : __j;
      |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
Matrix.hh:6:10: note: candidate: ‘bool compare_keys::operator()(const key&, const key&)’ <near match>
    6 |     bool operator() (const key& left_key, const key& right_key) {
      |          ^~~~~~~~
Matrix.hh:6:10: note:   passing ‘const compare_keys*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/map:60,
                 from Matrix.hh:1,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Base_ptr, const _Key&) const [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Val = std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; _Compare = compare_keys; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Link_type = const std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >*; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Const_Base_ptr = const std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:2570:22:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const _Key&) const [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Val = std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; _Compare = compare_keys; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:1215:31:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::size_type std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::count(const key_type&) const [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = compare_keys; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]’
Matrix.hh:23:9:   required from ‘bool Matrix<T>::emplace(int, int, T) [with T = int]’
main.cpp:7:5:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1945:6: error: no match for call to ‘(const compare_keys) (const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)’
 1945 |  if (!_M_impl._M_key_compare(_S_key(__x), __k))
In file included from main.cpp:3:
Matrix.hh:6:10: note: candidate: ‘bool compare_keys::operator()(const key&, const key&)’ <near match>
    6 |     bool operator() (const key& left_key, const key& right_key) {
      |          ^~~~~~~~
Matrix.hh:6:10: note:   passing ‘const compare_keys*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
```

The Matrix class:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::pair<int,int> key;
struct compare_keys {
    bool operator() (const key& left_key, const key& right_key) {
        if (left_key.first < right_key.first) return true;
        if (left_key.first > right_key.first) return false;
        return left_key.second > right_key.second;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
//Sparse matrix representation
    std::map<key, T, compare_keys> values;
    int max_row, max_col;
public:
    Matrix() : max_row(0), max_col(0) {};
    Matrix(int rows, int cols) : max_row(rows), max_col(cols) {};
    bool emplace(int row, int col, T value) {
        if (this->values.count(std::make_pair(row, col))) 
            return false;

        this->values[std::make_pair(row, col)] = value;
        if (row > max_row) max_row = row;
        if (col > max_col) max_col = col;
        return true;
    }

};
```

I don't see why the `compare_keys` operator doesn't match the comparator in the `map` constructor.

Comment: The most important parts of the message are "no match for call to ‘(*const compare_keys*) (const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)’" (my emphasis)  and "passing ‘const compare_keys*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers". It's a `const` mismatch.

Comment: Your comparator function needs to be `const`

Comment: Aside: `std::pair::operator<` exists, is there a particular need for a (subtly different) order here? Also have a look at [`map::try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace), which can simplify `emplace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `const`.

```
bool operator() (const key& left_key, const key& right_key) const {
                                                            ^^^^^
```